# Java not drawing desired graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics, draw, paintcomponent

This is a pretty simple program that just draws a white rectangle in a pop-up window.  The program compiles and runs no problem, and the windoe pops up, but there is nothing in it, it's just grey.  Why isn't anything drawing?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintcompnent(Graphics g) {
        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.add(panel);
        window.setSize(550,550);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, it wasn't working.  Thought maybe it was making a rectangle the same color as the background, so I switched to fillrect.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice the `fillRect` invocation, i thought you were using the `for` loop to manually draw the rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void paintcompnent(Graphics g)
```

Should be

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not correctly overridden the method. It should be:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {}
```

Note the use of the `@Override` annotation, which will prevent you from making this mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

After fixing the overridden method name, it still won't paint anything because you are filling the rectangle in white and then painting white lines on top.  You need to use `setColor()` to set something other than white to see the lines.